# create a command line argument .bat file that can change all .exe file compatibility settings in a specific directroy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple drives with a different directory structures.  I have a directory called "test files" with of several .exe files that I need to change the compatibility settings to "run this program as administrator"

Is it possible to create a windows .bat file that runs as Admin and that can change all the .exe files compatibility settings in a specific directory and all its sub-directories, regardless of where "test files" is located,  to "run this program as an Administrator"
 This is what I have thus far

```
for /r "J:test files\" %%A in (*.exe) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

Comment: `for /r R:\ %%a in (*.exe) do ...`

Comment: I have no real idea about why you're intending to modify all of those files. Surely all you need to do is to create a shortcut, and modify it to run your emulator, 'As administrator', and with `R:\ ` as your start-in directory. _Obviously for the other PC you'd use `'F:\Arcade PC"` as that 'start-in' directory_. All of the exe files run in that Administrator session should inherit those Administrative privileges.

Comment: If you individually change your hundreds of exe files to run as administrator, they will all run as administrator, (even those which don't need to)! If you're not running the emulator directly, then you'd invoke whatever you're using to launch it as administrator instead, i.e create a shortcut to that and check the run as administrator box; once again the elevation will be inherited.

Comment: Try `for /r J:\ %%A in (*.exe) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"`. Reference: [How-to: App compatibility](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-compatibility.html)

Comment: @michael_heath Thank you for explaining it at my novice level.  Your assistance is amazing.  I am just simply amazed at the possibilities of what a .bat file can do...I wish I knew more of this stuff.  I have so many things I would do with this knowledge.  I think of all the time I wast doing things over and over the long way.  I tried sending you a PM to thank you but I guess this site doesn't allow it.   Much appreciated.  I believe this solution for this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In batch-file named `runasadmin.cmd`:

```
@echo off
for /r "C:\test files\" %%A in (*.exe) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

Using `C:\test files\` as example path as most users will have a `C:` drive.

In interactive CMD Prompt:

```
for /r "C:\test files\" %A in (*.exe) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

This batch-file code will recurse the directory `C:\test files\` for `exe` files and register them in the Windows Registry to run as admin. The interactive CMD Prompt does not need the `for` variable `%A` to be escaped with another `%` as the command is parsed less times than the batch-file.

To make a batch-file that can accept a variable path, then this might be suitable, though has no argument check to validate:

```
@echo off
for /r %1 %%A in (*.exe) do reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"
```

The `%1` is a named variable that is replaced by the 1st script argument. If `%2` were used, it would be replaced by the 2nd script argument. `%0` is the command and `%1` to `%9` is the available arguments.

To pass the arguments, you can do it from a CMD Prompt, from a Shortcut, from the Windows Registry and from anywhere else that supports passing arguments.

The script `runasadmin.cmd` can be executed from anywhere on the system if placed in the system PATH. The Windows directory is in the system PATH so can copy `runasadmin.cmd` to that location. With `runasadmin.cmd` in PATH, open the File Explorer and navigate to the root directory of the `exe` files to register the `exe` files. Once there, type `cmd` into the Address Bar. A CMD Prompt will open and will be at the current directory of the File Explorer location. Enter `runasadmin.cmd` or the shorter `runasadmin` without the extension. This will run the batch-file code and register all `exe` files in the current directory and subdirectories.

If placing the script in PATH is unwanted, then open the File Explorer and navigate to the root directory of the script. Enter the path as an argument of where the root directory of the `exe` files are located. Once there, type `cmd` into the Address Bar. A CMD Prompt will open and will be at the current directory of the File Explorer location. If the `exe` files root directory is `C:\test files\`, then enter the command `runasadmin "C:\test files\"`. This will run the batch-file code and register all `exe` files in the directory of `C:\test files\` and subdirectories. Any valid directory path can be passed as the 1st argument.

Some variations to `runasadmin.cmd`:

```
@echo off

rem Ensure 1st argument is valid.
if not "%~1" == "" (
    if not exist "%~1" (
        >&2 echo Require a valid directory path as the 1st argument.
        exit /b 1
    )
)

rem Register the exe files.
for /r %1 %%A in (*.exe) do (
    reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN" /f >nul
)
```

- A check is done to ensure the 1st argument is valid.
- `%~1` is `%1` with surrounding double quotes removed.
- `>&2 echo` echoes the following error message text to the stderr stream.
- If `exit /b 1` happens, the `errorlevel` variable can be checked if it's value is `1`.
- `/f >nul` forces the add to registry and the success message is redirected to `nul`, which silences the success message. Error messages are not silenced.

```
@echo off
setlocal

@rem Display help message.
@if "%~1" == "/?" goto :help
@if "%~1" == "-h" goto :help

rem Assign all arguments to allargs.
set allargs=%*

rem Assign value of 1st argument to variable named root.
set "root=%~1"

rem Assign value of 2nd argument to variable named undo.
set "undo=%~2"

rem Enter a root path if no argument passed.
if not defined root set /p "root=Enter root path of exe files: " || exit /b 0

rem Remove any double quotes.
set "root=%root:"=%"

rem Ensure 1st argument is valid.
if not exist "%root%" (
    >&2 echo Require a valid directory path as the 1st argument.
    exit /b 1
)

rem Enter y or n to undo registration.
if defined undo (
    if "%undo%" == "1" set "undo=y"
) else if not defined allargs (
    set /p "undo=Undo registration [n|y]: "
)

if /i not "%undo%" == "y" set "undo="

rem Register the exe files.
for /r "%root%" %%A in (*.exe) do (
    echo ENTRY: "%%~A"

    if defined undo (
        reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /f >nul
    ) else (
        reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN" /f >nul
    )
)
exit /b 0

:help
echo Syntax: "%~nx0" [root [undo]]
echo:
echo Examples:
echo   To register exe files in "C:\test files\".
echo       "%~nx0" "C:\test files\"
echo:
echo   To undo register of exe files in "C:\test files\".
echo       "%~nx0" "C:\test files\" 1
echo:
echo 1st arg is root directory to search recursively.
echo 2nd arg set to 1 to undo registration.
echo:
echo No args will display prompt for root directory and if to undo.
exit /b 0
```

- `setlocal` to keep variables `set` in the script as local to the script.
- Value of all arguments is assigned to variable named `allargs` to later check if `allargs` is defined.
- Value of 1st argument is assigned to variable named `root`.
- Value of 2nd argument is assigned to variable named `undo`.
- 1st argument is required, else a prompt displays to ask for a root path.
- `if not defined root` is if variable name has no value which makes the variable name `undefined`.
- `|| exit /b 0` happens if input from the prompt is empty.
- Enter `runasadmin.cmd /?` at CMD Prompt for help with command line usage.

Suggest one of the later variations as they check for mistakes in the command line or input. The last code is the most featured.

if need help with a command such as `reg`, enter `reg /?` at a CMD Prompt to view the builtin help of the command.

---

References:

- [An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [How-to: Pass Command Line arguments (Parameters) to a Windows batch file](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [Command line parameters](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php)

Comment: Additionally, how do I give positive feedback on this site?

Comment: Perfect, the corrected post worked.  Thank you so much.  Along with your solution I have become slightly more educated, but still wish I had someone to verbally dummy this down.   Thank you again.  Can I give you a badge or kudos or something like that? It's just amazing what these scripts can accomplish

Comment: Is it possible to grant admin rights to certain known .exe files within the directory its subdirectories with one bat file?  For example,  I want to give admin rights to all the files named  test.exe, run.exe, load.exe  that are located inside "test files: directory and its subdirectories. I have made several attempts, but all failed.  I had tried to use the code you provided and made changes but can't figure it out `@echo off
for /r %1 %%A in (*.exe) do reg add  "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%%~A" /d "RUNASADMIN"`

Comment: [Example](http://users.tpg.com.au/mpheath/support/61302750.html) of `dir` piped to `findstr` using a strings file.

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial.  I am playing with it now.  I am having issues, but I want to see if I can figure it out.  One question I have is with the string.text...If I am understand this correctly, I need to place each directory into this string or just the actual .exe files I want changed.   the.xyz.exe sort of threw me off a bit.   I have hundreds of directories and sub-directories.  It's also hard to say which directory has the deepest/longest subdirectory.  It would take me quite a while to find this out.  I'm guessing I don't need to put each directory.

Comment: `findstr` matches strings. `/e` argument is end of string, so string `exe` will match all paths, as all will end with `exe`. How far left from the end of string is up to you to decide.

Comment: I have spent countless hours trying, but i am still unsuccessful.  I thought I could but, I have to waive the white flag.  I can't get the string text file correct